# Missing fonts folder in bower Materialize

Tags: javascript, fonts, bower, materialize, roboto

I just included Materialize in my project using bower, but unfortunately the **fonts** folder is keep missing from **./bower_components/materialize/dist/**.

[image]

**This is my bower.json**

```
{
"name": "teahrm",
"authors": [
  "Yusuf Ibrahim <mhyusufibrahim@gmail.com>"
],  
"description": "teahrm web app",
"main": "", 
"license": "MIT",
"homepage": "", 
"private": true,
"ignore": [
  "**/.*",
  "node_modules",
  "bower_components",
  "test",
  "tests"
],  
"dependencies": {
  "underscore": "^1.8.3",
  "backbone": "^1.3.3",
  "backbone.localStorage": "Backbone.localStorage#^2.0.0"
}
```

I checked it directly to the [github repository](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) and cloned it using git on my local environment and I realized that the fonts/roboto folder is already there (~/test/materialize/dist).

[image]

My question is:

1. what's wrong with my bower, why does it keep ignoring materialize/dist/font folder for being downloaded ?
2. How to fix it, or should I just add the fonts folder manually ?
3. Is the any other bower like package manager that more reliable than it?

Comment: I switched to use npm locally in my project then the materialize-css is structured correctly now (fonts folder is appear), just wondering why do people use buggy bower on their project instead of npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the materialize version "0.99.0" in bower.json fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

After I switched to use npm locally in my project then the materialize-css is structured correctly now (fonts folder is appear)

Not sure what is wrong with bower,but I realize that I can use npm (or yarn) in my project folder locally (I have no more reason to use bower in my project).

*just switched to yarn for better performance